# Google API PHP Client Library on GAE

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm trying to implement a button, that when clicked, will upload a generic file to Google drive. The following code works fine on my local machine (using Google's SDK for local dev), but when uploaded to Google App Engine it can't get past the require_once statement in slowtest.php. Here is my code:

HTML file:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="js/data.js"></script>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h2>Data Page</h2>
        <p>Press the button to upload a file.</p>

        <button onclick="upload()" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Upload</button>

        <p>Return: <span id="uploadedFiles"></span></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Calls upload() here:

```
function upload() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("uploadedFiles").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "slowtest.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And finally, the php file:

```
<?php

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
echo 'success!';
?>
```

If I remove the 'require_once' line, 'success' is added to the paragraph line on the webpage. However, when it isn't commented out, nothing happens when the button is clicked.

There is no error output on the page, but a 500 error is outputted to the console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I've run the same code on the command line and it works. If anyone has any suggestions, they would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you definitely got a __google-api-php-client__ directory in your applications directory, on the same level as your __app.yaml__?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ian. The folder is definitely there. I tried moving the files from within the google-api-php-client/src library into the main folder with everything else because within googles files, they mention includes in the form of 'contrib/afile.php', or 'auth/anotherfile.php', etc. and these files might not be found. Still am having the same error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed post [here](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/08/06/using-the-google-apis-client-library-for-php-with-app-engine/) on getting the PHP API client working with App Engine, which as far as I know is still accurate and works correctly.

I would suggest following the instructions in this blog post and report back if it still does not work.

Also, definitely do not put any paths in the api client directory in your app.yaml file, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem and it is pretty simple. I was referring to the google-api-php-client library as a static_dir, when instead none of the files are static.

<strike>Using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372129/how-to-configure-app-yaml-to-load-google-api-php-client-on-app-engine?rq=1) question helped efficiently solve this:</strike>

```
- url: /google-api-php-client/(.?)/(.?)/(.*)
  script: google-api-php-client/\3/\2/\1.php
```

**EDIT**: See the comment by IanGSY below. You don't need to mention the google-api-php-client library at all in your app.yaml.

Comment: This may work, but it is incorrect. You do not need to specify all application files as handlers, only files that you want to be accessible directly via urls. Your problem was having the google-api-php-client directory specified as a (static) handler, the fix is just to remove the entry completely from your app.yaml, no need to have the entry as above.